# Bing Maps Location api: Getting response as string

Tags: json, string, dictionary, bing-maps, bing

Hi I am using Bing location api to return the address of the user.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx

But the response it is returning is in JSON or XML. I want the same in string format that could later be stored in a list as plain text.

Comment: Where is this call being made? Are we talking front-end or back-end? What part of the response do you want to have as a string? Pretty much all languages have a json deserialiser/xml parser for you to be able to pick it apart, otherwise the responses *are* strings, basically. Please provide a little more context in your question so that an appropriate answer can be given.

Answer (score 0):

The location API returns JSON or XML as there is a lot of data in the response. It's not simply a single line of string. There are coordinates and address parts and names, multiple results. Parsing out the info you need is easy. If using .NET, use this library: https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit